# Android Kotlin - What happen to a background Runnable if the app is closed suddenly

Tags: android, kotlin, location, runnable, android-workmanager

I have this simple `MainActivity` in which I use the `WorkManager` to enqueue a unique `OneTimeWorkRequest`:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        WorkManager.getInstance(this).enqueueUniqueWork("work", ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE, OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(BackgroundTask::class.java).build())

        findViewById<Button>(R.id.button).setOnClickListener {
            BackgroundTask.stopHandler = true
        }
    }
}
```

The `OneTimeWorkRequest` launch a background `Worker` that is responsible to take updates from the `GPS_PROVIDER` whether the user keep the App in foreground or the user put the App in background:

```
class BackgroundTask (context : Context, params : WorkerParameters) : Worker(context, params){
    private lateinit var mLocationManager: LocationManager
    private lateinit var mLocationListener: LocationUpdaterListener

    private var mHandler: Handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
    private var mHandlerTask: Runnable = object : Runnable {
        override fun run() {
            if (Looper.myLooper() == null) {
                Looper.prepare()
            }
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"mHandlerTask running...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            if (stopHandler) {
                stopH()
                return
            }
            if (!isListening) {
                startListening()
            }
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, TEN_SECONDS)
        }
    }

    fun stopH() {
        stopListening()
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mHandlerTask)
    }

    override fun doWork(): Result {
        mLocationManager = applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager
        mLocationListener = LocationUpdaterListener()
        mHandlerTask.run()
        return Result.success()
    }

    private fun startListening() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission( applicationContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission( applicationContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0f, mLocationListener, Looper.getMainLooper())
        }
        isListening = true
    }

    private fun stopListening() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission( applicationContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission( applicationContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {
            mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListener)
        }
        isListening = false
    }

    inner class LocationUpdaterListener : LocationListener {
        override fun onLocationChanged(location: Location) {
            try {
                Log.d("DEBUG", "${location.latitude} , ${location.longitude}")
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            } finally {
                stopListening()
            }
        }
        override fun onProviderDisabled(provider: String) {
            stopListening()
        }
    }

    companion object {
        const val TEN_SECONDS: Long = 10000
        var isListening = false
        var stopHandler = false
    }
}
```

I put a `Toast` message inside the `run` of the `Runnable` object just to have confirmation the Runnable is going.

If I use the `button` in the `MainActivity` to stop the `Handler` everything works fine: the `stop()` function is called and then the `LocationListener` and the `mHandlerTask` callback are removed.

I was wondering what happens if I suddenly close the App (swiping up the App from the Recents Screen), because I can't see the `Toast` message prints anymore and so I guess someway the `Runnable` object is killed, but I want to be sure that also the `LocationListener` and the `mHandlerTask` callback are removed.

Does this happen automatically?

Comment: Yes, once you kill your app unless you started some sort of service, all of that is destroyed.

Comment: ok, as I imagined...Thanks!

Comment: @Rafa But if I need to do some operations inside the `onLocationChanged` method, for instance say couple of Volley `StringRequest`s, how can I guarantee these operations have been commited before my App comes destroyed?